# When cropping drawn rectangle from pictureBox and assign the cropped image to the pictureBox why it's zoom in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

form1 top

```
Rectangle rect;
bool painting = false;
```

constructor

```
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

pictureBox1 mousedown event

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
                painting = true;
            }
        }
```

picturebox1 mousemove event

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, Math.Min(e.X - rect.Left, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - rect.Left), Math.Min(e.Y - rect.Top, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - rect.Top));
            }
            this.pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
```

picturebox1 paint event

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (painting == true)
            {

                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                }
            }
        }
```

picturebox1 mouseup

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Image tmp = pictureBox1.Image;
            pictureBox1.Image = SaveRectanglePart(pictureBox1.Image, rect);
            if (tmp != null)
                tmp.Dispose();
        }
```

And the method SaveRectaglePart

```
public Bitmap SaveRectanglePart(Image image, RectangleF sourceRect)
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap((int)sourceRect.Width, (int)sourceRect.Height);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0.0f, 0.0f, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            return bmp;
        }
```

The problem is when I draw a rectangle over the pictureBox1 and then when it's getting ot the mouse up event what I want it to do is to replace the current image in the picturebox1 with the image inside the rectangle I drawed.

stretch the image in the drawn rectangle and assign it ot the pictureBox1 so now in the pictureBox1 I will have the cropped image from inside the drawn rectangle.

But what i'm getting in the pictureBox1 is zoomed in image. Can't figure out why.

This is a screenshot when I draw the rectangle

[drawn rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6qB2.jpg)

And this is a screenshot of what i'm getting in the mouseup event.

[zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFGwu.jpg)